# symfony (propel) can't generate schema

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, propel, phing

I'm using symfony 1.4.19 and php 5.4.8.
I think the problem appeared after upgrading php from 5.3 to 5.4...

When I thy to generate schema.yml with a

```
php symfony propel:build-schema
```

I recieve an error:

```
PHP Strict Standards:  Declaration of UnixFileSystem::getBooleanAttributes() should be compatible with FileSystem::getBooleanAttributes($f)
```

I have made a bit of search so far and I've learned that updating phing might help, but I already have version 2.4.13 and that's latest release and the error still appears.

Did anyone encounter that problem before?

Comment: Are you using sfPropelORMPlugin or sfPropelPlugin (shipped by default with symfony) ?

Comment: the default one - sfPropelPlugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really recommend you to switch to the official propel plugin for sf1.4: [sfPropelORMPlugin](https://github.com/propelorm/sfPropelORMPlugin).

You will have the last Propel 1.6 instead of 1.4. And sfPropelORMPlugin is now officially maintain by Propel guys.

And by the way, this problem is fixed in sfPropelORMPlugin : https://github.com/propelorm/sfPropelORMPlugin/issues/147